# Xamarin iOS app crash when start on iPad Air 2 with iOS 13.3.1

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I tried to start a Xamarin iOS app on iPad Air 2 with 13.3.1 as iOS

Partial log, I pasted full below via pastebin:

```
1   Incident Identifier: C8DA7CE0-06EF-4E08-A74A-60C8E455C3AA
    2   Beta Identifier:     FDF534D6-89BA-486F-988F-154845125DEB
    3   Hardware Model:      iPad5,3
    4   Process:             MyApp.Forms.iOS [1525]
    5   Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/8D581BA0-F6EE-4F49-9AA8-239728A46E68/MyApp.Forms.iOS.app/MyApp.Forms.iOS
    6   Identifier:          com.MyApp.R17
    7   Version:             99 (17.2004.0)
    8   AppStoreTools:       11C29
    9   AppVariant:          1:iPad5,3:13
    10  Beta:                YES
    11  Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
    12  Role:                Foreground
    13  Parent Process:      launchd [1]
    14  Coalition:           com.MyApp.R17 [662]
```

Here is full log:

https://pastebin.com/jHsNYDdf

There is image how I build Xamarin iOS on Latest visual studio for Mac

I started without problem on emulator with same iPad type and same iOS version ...

The issue happens on physical iPad ...

Can tell me what’s going wrong?

[image]

Comment: Your pastebin link is private and the part of the log you posted is not really useful to determine what is going on :)

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Sorry, I made it public now... the log is very very huge.

Comment: I tried in DEBUG and seems that is working. Strange

Answer (score 0):

> 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001891bfec4 __pthread_kill
>   + 8 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001890db1d8 pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 136 >(pthread.c:1458) 2   libsystem_c.dylib 
>   0x000000018902f8c0 __abort + 112 (abort.c:147) 3   libsystem_c.dylib
>   0x000000018902f850 abort + 112 (abort.c:118)

Occuring this error in physical device , sometimes because not adding permissions in **info.plist** . Maybe it will not occurs error in a simulator , however it can be in a physical device .

For example : adding Photo and Camera permission in `info.plist` ,

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Use Camera</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Use Photo</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>Use Photo addition</string>
```

Having a look at [Accessing Private User Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/security-privacy?tabs=windows#accessing-private-user-data) to check your needed permissions .

**Note** :

Apps that fail to provide the required keys will be silently terminated by the system when they attempt to access one of the restricted features or user information, ***without error***! If an app starts unexpectedly failing on iOS 10, ensure that all of the required **Info.plist** have been specified.

Comment: if is issue with permission, would this work on DEBUG mode or should crash as well ?

Comment: @SnakeEyes No matter debug or release mode , all can work in simulator and crash as well in a physical device .I think it's not related to the build model .

Comment: I deployed DEBUG mode on device and seems that run without problem...But on RELEASE, it happens to crash. Cannot find explanation

Comment: @SnakeEyes If need to run release mode , you should [enable debuging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYGlE.png).

Comment: @SnakeEyes Hi , if want to delive app to customers , you should configure the distribution provisioning profile . Have a look at [Xamarin.iOS app distribution overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/) . I think this is not related to build modle .